# How to upgrade gradle build in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build.gradle

Currently I am using Gradle Version 1.12. Now, I want to upgrade my gradle version to 2.16 in eclipse. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: 1.12? 2.16? They're both completely obsolete for years. Why don't you use the latest stable version (currently 5.3)? What does Eclipse have to do with this? You use the Gradle wrapper as documented, and import your project in Eclipse.

Comment: BTW, there isn't any version 2.16. See https://gradle.org/releases/